# Getting this error during an Integration Process, I am new to integration please help

Tags: integration

```
"errorCode": **"APEX_ERROR",
        "message": "System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input\n\nClass.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1\nClass.UserDataJSON.parse: line 23, column 1\nClass.ManageUsersOperation.getManageUsersInformation: line 15, column 1"**
```

// My Web Service Class looks like:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/manageUsers/*')
global with sharing class ManageUsersOperation{
    // get data using this request.
    @HttpPost
    global static RequestResponseJSON getManageUsersInformation() {
        RequestResponseJSON objReqRes = new RequestResponseJSON();
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        UserDataJSON objUserDataJSON = UserDataJSON.parse(request.requestBody.toString());
```

--------- More Code below --------------

// The JSON Parser Class is:

```
public class UserDataJSON
{
    public userInfoClass[] userInfo;
    
    public class userInfoClass
    {
        public String sfUserEmail;  
        public String kandyUsername;    
        public String kandyNumber;  
        public String kandyExtension;   
        public boolean isActive;
    }
    
    // This method is used to parse JSON value in to wrapper class.
    public static UserDataJSON parse(String json)
    {
        return (UserDataJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, UserDataJSON.class);
    }
}
```

// The JSON Payload I am supplying through Postman is:

```
{
  "sfOrgId": "0xDees300ofdmms",
  "userInfo": [
                {
                  "sfUserEmail": "kasim.14feb@gmail.com",
                  "kandyUsername": "syn.2000juxto.me",
                  "kandyNumber": "8600598946",
                  "kandyExtension": "2222",
                  "isActive": true
                },
                {
                  "sfUserEmail": "psatyani@synoptek.com",
                  "kandyUsername": "syn.2001@juxto.me",
                  "kandyNumber": "8888999099",
                  "kandyExtension": "7070",
                  "isActive": false
                }
              ]
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any `issue with the code snippet` from the description. Are you sure you're able to pass the payload in the request.

Comment: @Sachin Hooda I was able to pass the request with the same code two days before and it was reflecting in my salesforce object too, I don't understand what happened now as it's not working

Comment: Please make sure you are passing the request body correctly. I tried with the same code snippet provided and it worked. **Though I got the same error as you when not giving the body in the request so I believe the issue is body is not being passed somehow.** **Failed PostMan Request:**
Method: POST
Endpoint: https://umang-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/manageUsers
Body(Selected radio none): Response:
[ { "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR", "message": "System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input\n\nClass.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1\nClass.UserDataJSON

Comment: not best practice to include real (or what look like real) emails in post; use [edit] to fix